# How to validate user input in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, user-input

I'm working on a very simple Shiny app that takes in a DNA codon and returns the corresponding amino acid. My issue is that I want to validate the user input so that it can only accept 3 letter (a single codon), must be capital letters, and only accept the DNA bases ( A, C, T, or G). I've had a look at [Shiny's validation article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html), but keep on running into errors. 
Here is the code I have so far:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  theme = shinytheme("slate"),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Codon lookup"),

  # 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(
        inputId = "codon",
        label = "Enter a codon",
        value = ""),
      actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Search")
    ),

    # 
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("aminoacid")
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(Biostrings)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- eventReactive(input$go, {

    #validate somehow
      input$codon


  })


  output$aminoacid <- renderText({

    GENETIC_CODE[[as.character(data())]]

  })

})
```

Also, if anyone know of an easy way to retrieve the amino acid's full name, rather than just the single letter notation, that would be helpful. Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Any feedback for me?

Comment: @MikeWise Yes sorry, been busy today. This is excellent! I had thought about using selectInput but possibly wanted to extend this further in the future where users could input an entire sequence and have it translated. Awesome and helpful explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That reactive is not really the right place to do the validation in this case since you are not using GENETIC_CODE there. So I moved it into the `renderText` output node. If you had a `reactive` doing the lookup you could do it there.

I looked at GENETIC_CODE, and it seems to make more sense to do this as a dropdown anyway and use that as validation. So I went ahead and put a selectInput in there using renderUI, as you have more flexibility if you create the input control in the server usually.

I also moved the `Search` button to above the codon select control as it was getting covered up by the selection.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  theme = shinytheme("slate"),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Codon lookup"),

  # 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Search"),
      uiOutput("codonselection")
    ),

    # 
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("aminoacid")
    )
  )
))

library(Biostrings)

s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    input$codon
  })
  output$codonselection <- renderUI({
    choices <- names(GENETIC_CODE)
    default <- "TTC"
    selectInput("codon",label="Select Codon",choices=choices,selected=default)
  })

  output$aminoacid <- renderText({
    lookupcodon <-as.character(data())
    if (lookupcodon %in% names(GENETIC_CODE)){
      return(GENETIC_CODE[[ lookupcodon  ]])
    } else {
      return("Name not in GENETIC_CODE")
    }
  })

})
shinyApp(u,s)
```

Screen shot of it working:

[image]